# node.js TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

node.jsのexpressで、GETリクエストされた値をJavaScriptプログラムで処理変換して、レスポンスとして返すAPIサーバーをつくっています。

GETリクエストされたら、値を処理変換するJavaScriptプログラムを実行したいのですが、以下のように書くと、new explorers.Insight();の箇所でTypeError: undefined is not a functionというエラーが発生し、プログラムが停止してしまいます。

new explorers.Insight();をexplorers.Insight;に修正すると、エラーは止みましたが、今度はinsight.getUnspentUtxosというメソッドでTypeError: undefined is not a functionとなりました。

エラーへの対処と、そもそも「GETリクエストされた値を、JavaScriptプログラムで処理変換して、レスポンスとして返す」にはこのような書き方で合っているのか、教えてください。

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.get('/word:word', function (req, res) {
 var bitcore = require('./bower_components/bitcore/bitcore-lib.min.js');
 var explorers = require('./bower_components/bitcore-explorers/bitcore-explorers.min.js');
 var insight = new explorers.Insight(); //ここでTypeError: undefined is not a functionとでる

//以下にGETリクエストを受けたときの処理が続く

  res.send(req.params.word);
});

app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log("Node app is running at localhost:" + app.get('port'))
});
```

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> new explorers.Insight();の箇所でTypeError: undefined is not a function

本来 new に指定するものは関数でなければならないのに「undefinedは関数ではない」というエラーで、要は `explorers.Insight` が定義されていないということです。
<sub>※「Insightが見つからない」といったエラーでないのは、未定義のプロパティ参照自体はエラーにならないためです。</sub>

原因ですが、 `bitcore-lib.min.js` や `bitcore-explorers.min.js` は Node.js 用ではありません。Node.js上で使う場合は、別途 npm を使ってインストールしてください。

```
# この場合 bitcore-explorers に必要な bitcore-lib は自動的にインストールされるので、
# bitcore-lib を直接使わないなら別途インストールする必要はありません。
npm install bitcore-explorers --save
```

Node.js には `require()` でモジュールを読み込む機能がありますが、ブラウザには `require()` が用意されていません。そこで Browserfy というツールでブラウザ向けに変換したものが `bitcore-explorers.min.js` です。これはもはやNode.jsのモジュールではなく、Node.jsでは使えません。

Node.js 向けライブラリの配布に使われる npm と、ブラウザ向けライブラリの配布に使われる bower。パッケージ名が同じでも中身が同じとは限らないので、用途に合った方を選ぶ必要があります。